# UICollectionView is not updating properly - used THStringyFlowLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When my app starts, it takes data from the persistence and displays 5 cells in my Collection View. These cells looks like normal TableView cells, but I use Collection View for later layout tweaks. It takes 8 cells to fill whole screen.

A second after that, the model is updated with the data for 19 cells and the Collection View is updated by calling:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Those already displayed 5 cells are nicely refreshed with new data, but that's it. The other cells are not displayed until I touch the screen and scroll down about the height of the cell. Then instantly 3 cells are displayed and fills the screen. From that moment, everything is fine, but until I scroll, it is not updated correctly.

When I debugged it, I see, that the collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: is called after calling reloadData and it returns correct number 19, but the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: is asked just for those 5 cells (until I scroll).

Kind of desperate here, thanks for your help.

**Edit - added source code:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.manager.jubilees count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DLog(@"asked for cell: %i", indexPath.row); //just for debugging to know, what is going on
    JUJubileeCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"JubileeCell"
                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.jubilee = self.manager.jubilees[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

// called when model is updated
-(void)jubileesUpdated {
    DLog(@"jubileesUpdated");
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

**edit 2:**
When first 5 cells are loaded, the [self.collectionView contentSize] is (width=320, height=358).
When the all 19 cells are loaded and reloadData called, contentSize is (width=320, height=1366) - but cells are not actually displayed :(.

**edit 3:**
The problem is caused by using THStringyFlowLayout - I will post more, if I find the reason.

Comment: What happens if you don't scroll but wait like a minute or so? Might be thread related. Late appearing cells are a symptoms of calls made from a thread that is not the main thread. So make sure that reloadData is called from the mainThread. For example by adding a `NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"not on main thread");` before `reloadData`. That's basically the only problem I can imagine with such a result.

Comment: It is very good point, but unfortunately it is updated on the main thread :(. I already switched off all multithreading when I start dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everybody, thanks for the help!

The problem is somewhere in the Flow Layout. I am using THSpringyFlowLayout (which is the reason, why I am actually using Collection View) and without it, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding all the index paths you want to refresh into an array and  try using
 **[_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:arayOfAllIndexPaths]**

Comment: Thanks, it would work, but it is very ugly and brutal solution (create several NSIndexPath objects and use them only in one very particular case to prevent this strange behaviour). There must be something wrong in principal and this is not the solution I am looking for. But thanks, anyway!

Comment: Ok, I tried that (really desperate :)) and it actually does not work neither: _*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionViewData.m:597_ :)

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a shot in the dark, but this sounds like it might be a redraw bug. Try sending `-setNeedsDisplay` to the collection view to make it redraw itself.

Answer (score 1):

Reload your collection view on main thread

Comment: i dont know why u were downvoted. this was the solution to my problem since i was trying to reload after task completion using AWS S3. solution was to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without seeing any actual code but make sure that the dimensions of the cells are right, either from your item size delegate or from the parameters on the flowlayout (whatever you are using).

For what you described it seems that the collection view thinks that only 3 cells are visible, and since cell loading is lazy according to shown cells it's only dequeueing the first 3.

Edit: also make sure that you are passing the right indexPath to the dequeuecell method.

Comment: I added source code. Sorry, I should have paste it here at the first place. But there is not much to see :(.

Comment: I am still debugging, see my Edit 2. Thanks.